# Can to setup environment variable during build time

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, drone.io, terra

We are using Drone and terraform for CI/CD for react application. Can you please help me to create environment variable dynamically during build.

Comment: What you have tried so far? It's a good practice to include more details, regarding the trial/fails and as well as details about the codebase or configs.

Answer (score 0):

Setting env at build time means that bundle will only work in a particular environment. You will need seperate builds for each env.

Answer (score -1):

Remember that your env variables have to start with `REACT_APP_`. Add an `.env` file containing `REACT_APP_MYVARIABLE=something`
and build your app as usual or juzt build it like so:

- (windows) `set "REACT_APP_MYVARIABLE=something" && npm run build`,
- (macOS, linux) `REACT_APP_MYVARIABLE=something npm run build`.

Then, you can access your env variable from within your code like so: `process.env.REACT_APP_MYVARIABLE`.

Comment: Thank you for checking. I have created .env file which has variables assigned with plain text values. I am wondering is there any way we can dynamically provide the values while building an application.

Comment: I precisely wrote that.